# Allegro5 - openGL: Major opcode of failed request: 55 (X_CreateGC)

Tags: c++, allegro5

I have been trying to get Allegro5 up and running on my Ubuntu machine. I compiled this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
  if (!al_init()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  display = al_create_display(640, 480);

  if (!display) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
  al_flip_display();
  al_rest(10.0);
  al_destroy_display(display);
  return 0;
}
```

Received this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  55 (X_CreateGC)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x4000002
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  27
```

Tried this solution:
http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/607530
(changed allegro5.cfg to be "config_selection=old" and installed mesa-utils).

I am not sure what to try now.

Comment: I would clear your build folder and start over, making sure you've got all the dependencies installed. (See http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian for details.) It should work without any problems on Ubuntu.

Comment: I ran through all the dependencies in the list. Do I have to manually add the OpenGL library somewhere? Or does it need to have mesa-utils installed before I run ./configure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Allegro 5 doesn't use `./configure`. If all those dependencies are installed via `apt-get` when you use `cmake`, it should work.

Comment: Well, it is working now. The problem was the video card configuration was wrong on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured xorg.conf to use dri and glx.